# How can I access MainActivity's objects or methods inside BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm creating an android app that uses *AlarmManager* to create an alarm by playing a sound. To do this, I first create a PendingIntent, for which I have to create a class called *AlarmReceiver*, which extends *BroadcastReceiver*. In this new class, I override the onReceive method, in which I also start the sound. What I have right now works. However, as part of a bigger project, I will be later getting some data from a database. Regarding my question, this data is not important; what's important is that, after analyzing all the data, it will all come down to a boolean variable, which will be true or false. This variable will be in *MainActivity* and I want to access it in my *BroadcastReceiver* class to check it and if true, I would stop the music. I've checked many SO questions related to these, but I still haven't found a solution.

The code for the MainActivity is:

```
package com.example.alarmsound;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
    t.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

    Context context = this;
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    boolean result; //the variable I want to access to BroadcastReceiver class
}
}
```

And the code for the BroadcastReceiver class is:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public AlarmReceiver() {}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music);
    Log.d("Music", "It went here.");
    mp.start();

    //here, I want to access result
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You can put result as an extra in the Intent that your BroadcastReceiver is listening to.

Comment: If you want to access the methods, you could cast the Context, but I wouldn't recommend that because you may get a ClassCastException if you aren't careful

Comment: You can also use SharedPreference to store the boolean value in order to access the result across application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of your `MainActivity` and get it using a method, add following code in your `MainActivity`:

```
private static MainActivity instance;

@Override
protected void onStart() { // onStart() of your activity
    super.onStart();
    instance = this;
}

public void yourMethod(){
    // Your code here
}

public static MainActivity getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
```

Now, in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you can get the instance using:

```
MainActivity obj = MainActivity.getInstance();
```

And you can call your method using:

```
obj.yourMethod();
```

Comment: Don't do this.  You will leak the main activity object. It might work in the short term, but this could cause problems later.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. If you must, make "result" static, but definitively not the whole activity. But that's still not the right solution.

Comment: I think I see what you mean guys. I accepted the answer because it actually solved my problem and my program worked also as part of my whole project, which I just finished yesterday. But I will keep this in mind in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("some_constant", result);
```

In your broadcast receiver:

```
boolean result = intent.getBooleanExtra("some_constant", false);
```

Comment: I just tried it and if I set result to true in MainActivity and I access it in your way, it turns out to be false. I can see that by doing Log.d("result", Boolean.toString(result);

Comment: Did you copy it verbatim? There was a typo in the constant, it should be the same in the intent and in the receiver. Make sure the constants are all the same.